# Get out of custom fullscreen app

Tags: macos, mac, fullscreen

I'm developing a full screen app that I just launched that has apparently completely stolen the keyboard to the point where nothing can get me out. Not command-option-esc, not command-option-shift-esc, not command-tab, nothing. Moving the mouse to the edge of the screen doesn't bring anything up. Can someone help me before I just force shutdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an Apple keyboard, you could try using one of the function keys that brings up Mission Control or shows the desktop — typically <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd>, but it may vary depending on the vintage of keyboard (it may be <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>F4</kbd>/etc. depending on your system preferences).

If that doesn't work, try bringing up the shutdown dialog with either the power button or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>eject</kbd>. That might be enough to release keyboard control and allow you to <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> out. At the very least you should be able to perform a clean shut down.

Finally, if you happen to have Remote Login enabled (in *Sharing Preferences*), you could SSH in from another machine and kill the errant process.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried all of that. Nothing worked. I've already forced reboot. But I'm going to set up ssh so I can kill it in future. Thanks.

Comment: Was your app still clearly running? If the power button didn't work, it may be that your system hard locked (which is unusual for a Mac, typically it kernel panics if fully locked up, but it's possible).

Comment: I still don't understand how a cocoa app took such full keyboard control. It's not a bad thing, as it is an education app for which control is a good thing, I just have to add a get out of fullscreen option.

Comment: nope. The mouse still moved, and pandora still played. I wouldn't call that a hard lock.

Comment: That is strange. My Cocoa knowledge is mostly limited to iOS, so I can't offer any help there, but perhaps run your full-screen code past [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) to check for anything wonky.

Comment: It was a straight copy of some code I say on the most popular so question on it. I think I'll just set up ssh and use my Linux laptop to ssh in if anything goes wrong. That's a good idea, thanks.